# apt-get command in google cloud vm

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, apt

I launched google clound vm with Ubuntu 16.04, when I issue command `sudo apt-get update`, I get back `apt-get command not found`? How can I install `apt`?

Comment: Maybe with aptitude instead of apt-get?

Answer (score 0):

Standard Ubuntu images available on GCP would provide `apt-get` in all cases.

You could be logged into:

- modified Ubuntu environment
- some sort of containerized environment running on top of Ubuntu
- not Ubuntu to begin with

Comment: I followed standard process to launch VM. Too bad I already deleted it. It was Ubuntu 16.04. I can try to reproduce it again. But now I launched Ubuntu 14.x and everything works fine

Comment: That would be quite weird if you can reproduce it. I've just created a fresh instance based on ubuntu-1604-xenial-v20170516 image and as expected apt is present.

Comment: @user1700890: also could be explained by this answer if you ticked Containers check-box in Cloud Console while creating the instance: https://serverfault.com/a/855484/21261